# iOS Simulator crashes when changing device type

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios-simulator

iOS simulator (Version 8.1 550.3) constantly crashes when trying to change Hardware -> Device type.

From the console logs I can get this information but I am unsure what's exactly the setting that causes the crash. To be honest, I haven't changed much of the boilerplate settings yet.

> Application Specific Information:
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'LaunchScreen''
>   terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   abort() called
>   CoreSimulator 110.4 - Device: iPhone 6 - Runtime: iOS 8.1 (12B411) - DeviceType: iPhone 6

Any ideas?

EDIT: I have tried to clean the build folder and "Reset Content and Settings" of Simulator as suggested in similar questions. They didn't fix the problem.

Comment: I generally end the simulator before changing device types.  Seems to be happier that way.

Comment: It makes the workflow way way too slower though.. :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try delete the content of the deriveddata folder:

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData